# "load 40 mcg" vs. "40 mcg load" - are they synonymous?

Tags: phrase-choice

1. Vertical electrophoresis under reducing conditions (**40 μg load**)
2. Vertical electrophoresis under reducing conditions (**load 40 μg**)

These are two variants of a legend under an [electropherogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electropherogram). The bolded phrase indicates that 40 micrograms of the product were [loaded into a well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyacrylamide_gel_electrophoresis) in the electrophoretic gel.

Are these two usages acceptable, or is one better than the other? I used **load 40 μg** but a fellow translator said she would prefer option 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"load 40 μg" is a little ambiguous in the sense that it could be read two ways.  It could mean "load" as a verb (i.e., this phrase is an instruction), or there could be an implied colon, as in "load: 40 μg" (i.e., load is acting like a label).  In this case, there is no practical difference in interpreting it either way.

"40 μg load" is unambiguous, and means the same as the second interpretation, above.

So there could be literal differences in meaning but in this example, they mean the same thing.